# jquery mousemove() - how to change cursor?

Tags: jquery, mousemove

i am using the mousemove() function. I've noticed it changes the mouse cursor to 'move' icon.

Is there a way to replace this with a custom image? i have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$("#main").mousemove(function(e) { 
$('#main').css('cursor: url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon.png"), auto;');
$('.ms-slide-info ').css('left', e.pageX + 10).css('top', e.pageY + 
5).css('display', 'block');
});

$("#main").mouseout(function() { 
$('.ms-slide-info ').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Working page here: http://emgs.scrappydog.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

change this

```
$('#main').css('cursor: url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon.png"), auto;');
```

to

```
$('#main').css('cursor', 'url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon.png"), auto');
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this but it didn't work. I have updated the URL with these changes.

Answer (score 1):

you have two errors:

first you do not set the css with jquery correctly. This is how it should look like:

```
$('#main').css('cursor', 'url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon.png"), auto;');
```

second you set the cursor of `#main` but there is a more specific element you are hovering and therefore it displays the cursor set with `.ms-grab-cursor`

Furthermore i do not understand why you want to set the cursor via javascript. why dont you just set it via css by overriding `.ms-grab-cursor`.

e.g.:

```
.ms-grab-cursor{
   cursor: url(/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mouse-icon.png), auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried both of these but it didn't work. I have updated the URL with these changes.

I only tried javascript because i thought it was the mousemove() that was creating it.